# Keep Elasticsearch connection alive

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm looking to keep my elasticsearch's client connection alive. I've been using the elastic client and had some great success with it when indexing and searching its datastore, but I want to be able to create a connection to my elasticsearch's nodes and preserve the connection so that I don't need to continuously create a new connection for every time I POST to it.

Having looked at the documentation I see there's a keep-alive feature for the swagger documentation but I've created my client using nodejs and have had no such luck finding any feature to do so.

my client looks something like this:

```
const client = new Client({
  auth: {
    username: 'aSecret',
    password: 'alsoASecret',
  },
  node: 'localhost:9000',
  maxRetries: 3,
  requestTimeout: 15000,
});
```

and my index is very simple right now:

```
await client.index({
  index: 'my-datastore'
  refresh: true,
  body: eventData,
});
```

How can I keep my index Connection alive so that I can send multiple events to my datastore without having to connect and reconnect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `keepAlive` config option in the `Client`'s constructor.
And its a boolean value. [Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/16.x/config-options.html)

`keepAlive`: Should the connections to the node be kept open forever? This behavior is recommended when you are connecting directly to Elasticsearch.

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  auth: {
    username: 'aSecret',
    password: 'alsoASecret',
  },
  node: 'localhost:9000',
  maxRetries: 3,
  requestTimeout: 15000,
  keepAlive: true
});
```

Comment: I've been staring at the wrong places of the documentation! Completely missed that, I really appreciate the example too. Thank you, and have a great day!